# Show that an order-isomorphism is necessarily a bijective mapping but the converse is not true.

Tags: solution-verification, lattice-orders, morphism

> Show that an order-isomorphism is necessarily a bijective mapping but the converse is not true.

**My try for the converse:** let $L=M=\{0,1\}$ and $f$ is defined by $f(0)=1,f(1)=0$. This can be easily verified that $f$ is bijective. But
\begin{equation*}
 f(0\wedge 1)=f(0)=1\ne 0=1\wedge 0= f(0)\wedge f(1)
 \end{equation*}
and \begin{equation*}
 f(0\vee 1)=f(1)=0\ne 1=1\vee 0= f(0)\vee f(1)
 \end{equation*}
That is $f$ is not a homomorphism.
Since $f$ is not a homomorphism, it is not isomorphism and hence cannot be order-isomorphism.

Is it correct?

Comment: That's fine, but the result is rather weak. A more classical exercise in Lattice Theory is that an order-isomorphism is a bijective **order-preserving** map, but the converse is not necessarily true. That is, there exist bijective order-preserving maps which are not lattice homomorphisms, and so not isomorphisms either.

Comment: something came up in my mind that I could do it another way like: $0\le 1\not\implies f(0)\le f(1)$ because $1\not\le 0$

Comment: That's why I wrote it's fine. But in your example, the map is not order-preserving as you stated in the comment. What I tried to bring your attention to, is that even if it were order-preserving and bijective, that wouldn't be enough to be an isomorphism.

Comment: I got your point. You meant order preserving + bijective $\ne$ isomorphism but bijective + homomorphism $=$ isomorphism.